# Mixing Java And Kotlin In Gradle Project, Kotlin Cannot Find Java Class

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

As the title says, I am trying to mix Java and Kotlin in a single project. There's a good example found here. [mixed-java-kotlin-hello-world](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/mixed-java-kotlin-hello-world). Everything is working properly besides kotlin cannot find any of my Java classes which are found in src/main/java/somepackage/SomeClass.java

What would be the cause of this?

This is the error I am getting.
[image]

When I try to edit my build.gradle, it shows I'm not spelling kotlin correctly and giving me errors on plugin but I'm copying and pasting from kotlins website.
[image]

My build.gradle looks like this

```
group 'Battle-OS'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.2-1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.2-1"
testCompile  'junit:junit:4.11'
testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.0.2-1"

compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.18'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '19.0'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all
compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.0.37.Final'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.moandjiezana.toml/toml4j
compile group: 'com.moandjiezana.toml', name: 'toml4j', version: '0.6.0'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib
compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib', version: '1.0.2-1'

}
```

Instead of starting off trying to make this work on a larger project. I tried to make this work by creating a new gradle project. I created a test java class which contains a method to print hello world. Then I created a test kotlin class which creates a new object of the java class and calls the method from the java class to print hello world.

This solves the problem I had above, now I can call java classes from kotlin and kotlin from java but now it gives me errors upon running it.

[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:      kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
at AKotlinClassKt.main(AKotlinClass.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

Comment: Do you get this error when building your project with command line gradle or do you see it in Eclipse only?

Comment: As far as I know it's only eclipse. I have no problem with this using IntelliJ, but I'm trying to make this project work with eclipse and IntelliJ.

Comment: How did you build your project?

I tried to build mixed-java-kotlin-hello-world and didn’t get any error. I imported project as ‘gradle’ one to eclipse, then added Kotlin nature to the project and built it using ‘Gradle tasks’.

Just in case, there is no corresponding import declaration on the first screenshot, please try to add it and build project again.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing, but I'm not using tasks to build the gradle project. I can import the class by manually doing it, but my IDE should automatically be finding the classes for me if I hover over the class. What Eclipse version are you using? I'm using Neon.

Comment: I get this issue when I try to import mixed-java-kotlin-hello-world http://prnt.sc/bn9m4e

Comment: Yes, for now, hover over an unresolved class doesn’t provide auto-import action. You can try to invoke ctrl+1 to find available actions and then import the class. Alternatively you can use 'organize imports' feature.

Comment: About the last problem: seems that there is a bug, workaround is to modify and save Kotlin source file. Could you please file an issue to the [bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT)?

Comment: @MikhailZarechensky Yeah I can do that.

Comment: @ChadAdams is problem solved

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you should override sourceSets like this

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = []
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/kotlin']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue and my java code was in the same source directory as the kotlin code

My solution was adding this configuration in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
configure<SourceSetContainer> {
    named("main") {
        java.srcDir("src/main/kotlin")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this thread using the Android Gradle plugin;

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        named("main") {
            java.srcDir("src/main/kotlin")
        }
    }
}
```