Mix Java and Kotlin in Gradle Kotlin DSL with sourceSet
I have a project that mixes Java and Kotlin.
The Java code in src/main/java calls  Kotlin code in src/main/kotlin.
The app is launched from the Kotlin part.

In the build.gradle.kts, the full content
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    java
    id("project-report")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.23"
}

group = "com.aaaaa"
version = "x.y.z-SNAPSHOT"


sourceSets {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131237/mixing-java-and-kotlin-in-gradle-project-kotlin-cannot-find-java-class
    main {
        java.srcDirs("src/main/java","src/main/kotlin") 
        kotlin.srcDir("src/main/java")
    }
}


java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.17.2")
    implementation("io.github.jbock-java:either:1.5.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.htmlunit:htmlunit:4.2.0")

    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation ("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1")
//  testRuntimeOnly ("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1")
}


tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

The Java code cannot find Kotlin code and I get this error during the build ./gradlew build:

Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
Compilation failed;

Strange thing, everything was working without explicitly sourceSets in Gradle before I updated to IntelliJ 2024.
What is wrong in the sourceSets configuration in order for the Java code to find Kotlin code? The app is launched from Kotlin part.
I read Building a Kotlin + Java 9 project with Gradle
The solution is to set the kotlin compilation directory to the same directory as Java:
compileKotlin.destinationDir = compileJava.destinationDir
This line is invalid in Gradle 8.7 Kotlin DSL.
Rant : Seriously why the Gradle team keeps changing the API in the same DSL language.

java.srcDirs("src/main/java","src/main/kotlin") kotlin.srcDir("src/main/java") - as for me that looks weird: javac can't compile kotlin, moreover that differs from accepted answer on SO topic you are referring to.

I edited in the post like you suggested. The fail  ':compileJava' is there.

kotlin.srcDir("src/main/java") is just wrong.

I wasn't looking at the right place.
I had module files. I deleted them
src/main/java/module-info.java
src/test/java/module-info.java

Basically  src/main/java/module-info.java require import of each library.
However I could not find  a way to import src/main/kotlin.
By deleting modules , it fixed.
Thanks everyone for your answers and comments, my build.gradle.kts had these configurations implictly.
By setting sourceSets , now the build explicitly targets these directories.
Anyone who encounters a trouble with in a single project mixing Java and Kotlin. Check if you have module-info.java versioned.

It's a lot easier than you think: Java and Kotlin work together out of the box. Let's take some reassurance from the Kotlin team1:

Kotlin is designed with Java interoperability in mind. Existing Java code can be called from Kotlin in a natural way, and Kotlin code can be used from Java rather smoothly as well.

And also2:

Adding Java classes to a Kotlin project is pretty straightforward. All you need to do is create a new Java file.

A lot of what you are doing is configuring the Java plugin. However, the Kotlin JVM plugin builds on the Java plugin, and in most cases you don't need to touch the Java plugin. Instead you are disturbing the configuration the Kotlin JVM plugin automatically does for you.
This means all these lines should be removed:
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs("src/main/java","src/main/kotlin") 
        kotlin.srcDir("src/main/java")
    }
}

And these can be removed:
// within plugins {} block
    java

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}


1 https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html
2 https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html#adding-java-source-code-to-an-existing-kotlin-project

Thanks for the explicit sourceSets and documentation link.
It was another problem due to module-info.java
